# GitHub Actions bot does not trigger a `release` workflow event?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a CI workflow that listens to the [`created`](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads?actionType=released#release) activity type for [`release`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release) webhook events:

```yaml
name: "Sync"

on:
  release:
    types:
      - "created"
```

If I create a release manually via GitHub UI, this sync workflow runs as expected.

However, this workflow doesn't work when the releases are made via [`git-release`](https://github.com/anton-yurchenko/git-release), a GitHub Action for generating releases automatically. Here's a link to my `release.yml` workflow:

https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-test/blob/d02ee246d8e371d02d6c4c2e72fbe8df9d94fe11/.github/workflows/release.yml

Is it normal for releases made by `github-actions` to not trigger a `release` webhook event?

This issue doesn't seem to be related to the `created` activity type. I tried to use `published` instead of that, but it didn't work.